# JavaScript: Is it possible to replace functions like Array.prototype.indexOf?

Tags: javascript, prototype

As the questions says,
is it possible to replace such functions with an own implementation?

Like:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function () {
    console.log("foo");             
};
```

That's - of course - a stupid replacement. But this is more about the possibility. I tried it, but then it seemed like at runtime it's not replaced.

My console logs the `foo`. But when I'm calling something like

```
[].forEach();
```

which also shout log `foo`, it does not work, until I replace the forEach function again in the console.

Comment: yes the underscore and lodash libraries do exactly this.

Comment: The replacements do work, but they don't *permanently* affect the browser, if that's what you're asking. You have to alter the Array prototype in each JavaScript context (like, each page).

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't work? check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cmzrd

Comment: What you mean with context? Like each `<script>`-Tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example works:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function () {
    alert("foo");             
};    

[].forEach();
```

http://jsbin.com/xidew/1/

This is ultimately, undesirable though. You are altering the fundamental functions on which applications and libraries work. If you do alter these functions, you must be cautious to not break the way existing functions depend on them.

Looking at the way underscore.js edits [forEach](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/0525f0ecde565deb2787e73a4928764856bbb253/underscore.js#L94-L112):

You can see that they avoided changing the way every array uses `forEach` by creating a separate `_.forEach()` function.

Then other libraries, like Backbone, take that `forEach` and only override their *subclass* of array. Like Backbone overrides the `forEach` method in the Backbone collection.

**The moral of this story is:**

Its an extremely rare case to modify the prototype of base object classes, `String`, `Array`, `Object`, because of the possibly cataclysmic implications. If you need to, you can create a subclass of those base classes and modify it there to suit your own purposes. This tactic of subclassing is evident in Backbone and other popular and widely used js libraries.

Comment: I'm aware of this. This is more like to gain an deeper understanding of the language.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß I added more insight as to how others have pragmatically modified methods like `forEach`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working in the first place, but you're right, it's overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add the code to an external file default.js and add an script tag to the layout html (the main page that all the rest of the pages use)

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="Content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/default.js"></script>
</head>
```

It will always be picked up by other js code as it will be always loaded in the page.